# Prometheus metric name for zombie processes and number of user logged in

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

I need to write prometheus alerts to find out zombie process and total user logged in. but i could not find relevant metric for above 2 alerts.

additionally, if particular matric is not available, then is there any any way to write my own code in go/shell/python and add to node_exporter?

Answer (score 1):

Your two options would be writing [your own exporter](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/writing_exporters/) or adding metrics to node_exporter via [textfile collectors](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/blob/master/README.md#textfile-collector).

For metrics like logged-in users or zombie processes I think the latter approach makes sense and you can find an example [here](https://www.robustperception.io/quick-sensor-metrics-with-the-textfile-collector/).

So, for example, to add number of logged-in users you can make a cronjob that runs

`echo users_logged_in $(who | wc -l) > /var/lib/node_exporter/textfile_collector/users.prom`

Answer (score 0):

For the **number of zombie processes**, node_exporter should be executed with  `--collector.processes` switch so `node_processes_threads_state{thread_state="Z"}` is the number of the zombie processes.

Also, for the **number of logged-in users** you need to add `--collector.logind` switch to the node_exporter startup command, then you can find the logged-in users with `node_logind_sessions{type="tty"}` in Prometheus or Thanos-Query.